# count ways of total Sum that contain numbers 1 till N in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

Given a number as total, I need to calculate the number of ways to represent the total between 1 and k(inclusive).
let say sum = 8 and tillMax = 2;
it would be like this

- [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
- [1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
- [1,1,1,1,2,2]
- [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
- [2,2,2,2]

the total ways to sum 8 from 1 to tillMax is about 5 ways

i tried it but always got zero

```js
function waysTosum(n, tillMax) {
  let counter = 0;
  if(n == 0) {
    return counter++
  }

  for (let i = Math.min(tillMax,n); i >= 1; i--) {
    waysTosum(n- 1, i)
  }

  return counter
}

console.log(waysTosum(8, 2))
```

is that something wrong in my recursion?

Comment: You're not capturing the output of your recursive call. Do something with the output of `waysTosum(n-1, i)`.

Comment: it always 0 i console.log

Comment: The reason why it always returns `0` is you don't update `counter` in `for` statement; There fore, counter remains `0`.

Comment: In addition, `counter` is always reset to 0 evrytime `waysTosum()` in the `for` statement is executed.

Comment: i console waysTosum(n-1, i) is always `0` that is why i dont know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue 1

In the `for` statement, you don't update `counter`; Therefore, `counter` remains at 0, which is set at the beginning of the function.

### Issue 2

Every time `waysTosum(n- 1, i)` is executed, `counter` is always reset to 0 by `let counter = 0`.

---

**Here is my solution:**

```
function waysTosum(n, tillMax) {
  if (tillMax > n) tillMax = n;

  let arr = Array(n).fill(1)
  let count = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; arr[i] < tillMax; j++) {
      count++;
      let lastNum = arr.pop();
      arr[i] += lastNum;
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```